# What's the best way to construct this grid using css + sass?

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I'm looking to build this grid.

[image: grid]

I'm just building a single, straightforward HTML page - nothing complex, and I won't need to reuse the code elsewhere. There will be 2 text boxes and two images that will just sit on this grid.

I was initially going to go down this route:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-responsive-grid-made-even-better-with-sass--cms-21540

Which does the job very well, but would I be better served using a framework (like Suzy), or another solution?

I'm essentially looking for best practices and how to adhere to engineering SOLID, KISS, DRY and YAGNI principles.

Comment: _There will be 2 text boxes and two images that will just sit on this grid._ The grid image you link to has 12 grid spaces, not 4. (Debatably, it has 36 grid squares). What kind of grid do you want - a 6x2 grid?

Comment: there are so many frameworks out there already why build your own - there are even sites that allow you to specify your needs and will then build the css for you

Comment: Nowadays, I would go for a combination of [grid-layout](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid) and [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) to achieve good responsibility without a bloated framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There will be 2 text boxes and two images that will just sit on this grid.

I can't reconcile the image in your question with the description, so I have gone for the description.

Here is a **CSS Grid**, containing two images and two textboxes:

```css
.grid {
display: grid;
width: 92vw;
height: 92vh;
margin: 1vh auto;
grid-template-columns: 46vw 46vw;
grid-template-rows: 46vh 46vh;
grid-template-areas: 
    "textbox image"
    "image textbox";
}

.textbox {
border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
padding: 6px;
}

.image {
background-image: url('http://placebear.com/800/400');
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div class="textbox" contenteditable="true">You can edit me - I am a textbox...</div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="textbox" contenteditable="true">I am also a textbox - you can edit me too...</div>
</div>
```